# Mockito.anyString() crashes with NPE in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, mockito

I am using espresso and I want to create a mock response for the content resolver.

When I use:

```
`when`(context.activity.contentResolver.query(
        ArgumentMatchers.isA(Uri::class.java), 
        ArgumentMatchers.isA(Array<String>::class.java), 
        ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), null, null))
.thenReturn(matrixCursor)
```

I get the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: uri 
at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:128)
```

Is it possible to create the mock response for the content resolver in such cases?

Comment: another problem is that you should not mix matchers and actual arguments when you mock functions. Instead of `null, null` you should use `isNull(), isNull()`

Answer (score 3):

That looks like a nullability issue. Mockito does not work that well with nullable types in Kotlin.

There is a library that handles this problem: https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin

I'd suggest you to check [anyOrNull()](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/blob/1.x/mockito-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/com/nhaarman/mockito_kotlin/Mockito.kt#L47) here and try something like

```
ArgumentMatchers.anyOrNull<String>(), isNull(), isNull()
```

Read [this article](https://medium.com/@elye.project/befriending-kotlin-and-mockito-1c2e7b0ef791) to gain full understanding of the problem and how to handle it any different scenarios.