# how to resolve - Parameter specified as non-null is null

Tags: java, android, kotlin, junit, kotlin-coroutines

I have unit test in which I am trying to check is a use case is called with the right parameters but I get an error

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method com.xx.xxx.clean.orderview.domain.OnStandUseCaseCoroutine$Params.<init>, parameter serviceType`

```
@Test
fun `when notifyOnStand is called then we create a TimestampedAction with the correct user id, vehicle, timestamp and pass that to the usecase`() {
    val actionCaptor = argumentCaptor<TimestampedAction>()
    val timestamp = DateTime.now()

    every(noServiceRequiredBus.get()).thenReturn(Observable.just(REQUESTED))
    every(timingsUpdater.timestampCalculator(any(), any())).thenReturn(timestamp)

    baseOrderViewPresenter.setView(view)
    baseOrderViewPresenter.notifyOnStand()

    runBlocking {
        verify(onStandUseCaseCoroutine).run(OnStandUseCaseCoroutine.Params(any(), any(), capture(actionCaptor)))
    }
}
```

Use case which will get called when when called `baseOrderViewPresenter.notifyOnStand()` from tets case

```
class OnStandUseCaseCoroutine @Inject constructor(
    private val orderRepository: OrderRepository,
    private val serviceOrderTypeProvider: ServiceOrderTypeProvider
) : UseCaseCoroutine<GenericResponse, OnStandUseCaseCoroutine.Params> (){

    override suspend fun run(params: Params) =
        orderRepository.notifyOnStandSuspend(serviceOrderTypeProvider.apiPathFor(params.serviceType), params.id, params.action)

    data class Params(val serviceType: String, val id: String, val action: TimestampedAction)
}
```

Presenter layer which has the call to use case

```
private fun onstandUseCaseCoroutines(serviceType: String, id: String, action: TimestampedAction, callback: (GenericResponse?) -> Unit) {
    try {
        onStandUseCaseCoroutine(OnStandUseCaseCoroutine.Params(serviceType, id, action)) {
            callback.invoke(it)
        }
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        onStandResponseErrors()
    }
}
```

how can I fix this please

I tried changing to bellow code but that did not fix it, I am not sure what to do the `capture(actionCaptor)` bit if that is the issue

```
 runBlocking {
        verify(onStandUseCaseCoroutine).run(OnStandUseCaseCoroutine.Params(anyString(), anyString(), capture(actionCaptor)))
    }
```

Any suggestions please

Thanks
R

Comment: The issue is originating from passing null value to serviceType String parameter. Try to not hide codes with any.. any.. methods so we can find the cause

Comment: Hi, when I changed from `any()` to `anyString()` the error went away for `serviceType` and `id`

Comment: and for `capture(actionCaptor)` I am not sure how to do like I did not `anyString`

Comment: Are you using mockito ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49082459/1791771

Comment: yes I am using mockito, MockitoHelper